# Scanner misread with SerialPort class

Tags: c#, serial-port, barcode, barcode-scanner

time to time scanner are misreading barcodes. barcodes are in AN 8 standard. after scanning barcode it showing not the exact one but some from already scanned in the past. check sum is enabled. Reader service is up on linux

```
var serialPort = sender as SerialPort;
var barcode = serialPort.ReadExisting();

var lastBarcode = barcode.Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries).LastOrDefault();
```

this way i get lastScanned barcode and queuing the results

Comment: How are you deterring the start and end locations of received data?  You have to read scanner documentation and make sure you start looking at  data at beginning of the received data and wait until you get all the receive data before running the rest of your code.  You may need to flus your buffers before reading.,

Comment: SerialPort class does it for you. There are the local buffer, and ReadExisting flushes all the data.
start and end splitted by Environment.NewLine (/r/n)

Comment: Most of times data is correct, but once a week 1-2 month occurs

Comment: Serial Port does NOT align data and make sure you get data in one chunk.  Most of the time it usually work, but poorly written software will have issues with the serial port.  I've been fixing issues with serial ports for more than 40 years.

Answer (score 0):

Serial port communication is non-procedural communication in units of one character (usually byte) and does not correspond to the specifications of the barcode scanner.
One barcode notification may be divided into multiple reads, one read may notify multiple barcodes, and one read data may not match the beginning and end of the barcode format.

As commented, you need to check all the data you receive, determine if it follows the format notified by the barcode scanner and cut it out.
And if you decide to discard the data that does not follow the format, or if you decide that you have not received all the data yet, you need to save it in a buffer, concatenate it with the next notified data, and then check it again.

Comment: Is it clear that misreads are rare?

Comment: There are many possible factors, such as how to read / interval barcodes and how sophisticated the application program is. For example, it will easily occur when a large number of multiple barcodes are read during a test or by an expert operation.